# Quickest way to switch order of comma-sparated list in Vim

Tags: vim

Supose I have a function such as

```
myfunc(arg1 = whatever, arg2 = different)
```

I would like to transform it to

```
myfunc(arg2 = different, arg1 = whatever)
```

What is the quickest command sequence to achieve this? suppose the cursor is on the first "m". My best attempt is `fadt,lpldt)%p`.

Comment: I think your attempt is pretty good. I cannot think of a better way.

Answer (score 2):

There is a vim plugin: [vim-exchange](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange)

- visual select `arg1 = whatever`
- press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>
- visual select `arg2 = different`
- press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you change it a bit so it will work from wherever the cursor is and so that it will work on any arguments:

```
0f(ldt,lpldt)%p
```

All I changed from your method was I added `0` to move the cursor to the beginning and I changed `fa` to `f(l` so that it will work regardless of argument name.

Now you can either put this into a macro, or, if you use it a lot, you can make it a mapping:

```
nnoremap <C-k> 0f(ldt,lpldt)%p
```

I arbitrarily chose Ctrl-k here put you can use whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin for manipulating function arguments called [Argumentative](https://github.com/PeterRincker/vim-argumentative). With it you just execute `>,` and the argument your cursor is on will shift to the right. It also provides argument text object in the form of `i,` and `a,`.

Answer (score 0):

With pure vim, with your cursor at the start of the line:

```
%3dB%pldt,lp
```

This is the quickest I could think of on the spot (12 strokes).
This should work for all names as long as there is always a space around the equal signs.

```
%     " Jump to closing brace
3dB   " Delete to the beginning of 3 WORDS, backwards
%     " Jump to the beginning brace
p     " Paste the deleted text from the default register
l     " Move right one character
dt,   " Delete until the next comma
l     " Move right one character
p     " paste the deleted text from the default register
```

You could also turn this into a Macro to use at any time.